# Firefox events not firing

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have a list of eventlistners for a drag'n drop feature.

```
td.addEventListener('dragenter', onDragEnter);
td.addEventListener('dragleave', onDragLeave);
td.addEventListener('dragover', onDragOver);
td.addEventListener('drop', onDrop);
```

In firefox, the `drop` event is not fired when an item is dropped. The functions called for `dragenter`, `dragover` and `dragleave` each prevent default action (copied from http://mereskin.github.io/dnd/):

```
const onDragEnter = e => {
  onDragOver(e);
  console.log('onDragEnter:');
  if(e.target.nodeType == 1) {
    e.target.className = 'drop-over';
}  };

const onDragOver = e => {
  console.log('onDragOver:');
  if(e.target.nodeType == 1) {
    e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = e.target.getAttribute('data-drop-effect');
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
}  };
```

On http://mereskin.github.io/dnd/ all events seem to work (tried to have same methods, eventlisteners, etc).
The draggable item is construced with the specific attribute:

```
let img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = `icons/${obj._image}`;
img.setAttribute('draggable','true');
```

In Chrome it works perfectly, on my and the linked website.

Edit: Tried Edge as well, works fine. Tried also FF on another machine, same result. Created a jsfiddle for demo: https://jsfiddle.net/as965dkz/6/

Comment: would you create either a snippet from your code or a jsFiddle out of it? beside your markup?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/as965dkz/6/ In chrome it works, in firefox it doesn't

Comment: @Teemu, even if I allow propergation it still does not work

Comment: How about attaching the drop event to window or document?

Comment: Nope. Still same story. It does not even prevents the default action, so it always redirects me to the location of the img I dropped on to the td element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I found out, Firefox requires that `dataTransfer.setData()` is set at the `dragstart` event. Afterwards, on the drop event `e.preventDefault();` must be called.